# When do public member variables die?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have the following C++ class:

```
class DEF
{
   //...
}

class ABC
{
   public:
      DEF my_def;
      ~ABC();
   //...
}
```

And somewhere:

```
ABC* abc = new ABC(...);
delete abc;
```

My question:

Will my_def be accessible after calling delete abc? Is it safe to do `abc->my_def.somefunc()` **after** the delete?
 -

Comment: When data members die has nothing to do with whether they are public or not.

Comment: _"Is it safe to do abc->my_def.somefunc() after the delete?"_ No. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: No. The object is deleted. If you want to keep `my_def` around, you should store it elsewhere.

Comment: You should get a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1). You'll find out all about variable lifetimes there.

Comment: Accessible, yes, but the results of doing it are undefined. Safe? Absolutely not. Big no.

Comment: Even though my_def is not a pointer?

Comment: This would be like knocking down a house and expecting the second floor washroom to still be untouched and suspended in the air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, after `abc`'s destructor ran, its members will be destroyed in reverse order of their declaration. When `abc` is deleted, all its memory is free'd. That includes `my_def` in your example.

Maybe this question will be useful to you: [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/106508/416224)

Addendum: One major problem with C++ is [*undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/416224). Programming errors such as [use-after-free](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/416.html) may appear to work 80% of the time, if the memory was not reused in the meantime. But chances are that you overwrite unrelated memory and/or allow reading foreign data. That is a severe security problem, and a crashing program is the best you can hope for at this point.

Comment: @今天春天, you are mistaking C++ for a memory managed language such as Java or Python. Please read the answer in the linked question and look up any concept you don't understand.